# does centripetal force exist at terminal velocity?

Tags: centripetal-force

If a stone tied to string is spun it shall accelerate towards the center.  However if it reaches terminal velocity shall the stone be in the center exactly ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the down vote here.

Answer (score 1):

@Enns - yes so putting it another way shall the radius reduce over time if the velocity continues to increase ? Would the stone after some time end up in the center  (having zero radius) or would the acceleration  always remain perpendicular to the velocity ?

Answer (score -1):

The acceleration towards the center is perpendicular to the velocity of the stone so it does not change its speed only its direction so the stone will not speed up.

*Terminal velocity* usually referrers to something falling (or floating) through a fluid at the point where the drag forces from the fluid balance the weight (or buoyant force).  It's a different situation than the swinging in a circle situation you describe.

Comment: I don't think it's different at all.  Terminal velocity relates to the speed of objects in a fluid.  The stone is an object, the air is a fluid.

Comment: Its different because in the case of terminal velocity there is a constant force, say gravity, in the direction of motion  and a resisting force that is proportional to the speed through the fluid.  Once the speed increases enough the resisting force matches the constant force and speed becomes constant.  In the question the constant centripetal  force *is not in the direction of motion*, it does not increase the speed so the resisting force does not increase.  Terminal velocity is not reached.

Comment: I see.   I took the question another way, but I think you are right.

Comment: I don't find the question very clear.  I think the OP thinks the continuous centripetal acceleration will increase the stones speed until it reaches a terminal speed and also that the acceleration towards the center acts to reduce the radius over time.

Comment: @Enns - yes so putting it another way shall the radius truce over time if the velocity continu to increase ? Would the stone after some time end up in the center  (having zero radius) or would the acceleration  remain perpendicular to the velocity ?

Comment: @OverLord sorry, what do you mean by "truce"?

Comment: @OverLord  It would be better to clarify your question by editing the original question.  You have more space there, and people seeing it for the first time will know what you mean.  Make the effort to be as clear as possible.  I'll note that even with your comment above, I do not understand the question.

Comment: excuse me for the typo - i meant reduce.